MacBook Pro Monterey keeps dropping Android Hotspot WiFi
UPDATE: I changed wifi frequency to 5Gh in Android, it seems like it's working now.
I have recurrent problem - sometimes it works fine for hours. But sometimes it starts dropping Android HotSpot WiFi every 15 minutes or so.
The Mac has a hard time reconnecting back after dropping, sometimes it connects, but sometimes it can’t and the progress wheel on wifi just keeps rolling and rolling. I had to rename the wifi net name in Android, and only then it connects, instantly without any problem.
Is there any solution?
Android Details:
2.4Gh
WPA2-Personal
Broadcast channel: auto
Mac address type: randomized MAC
Turn off if no device connected: Never timeout
Hidden network: false
Protected Management Frames: false
Wifi sharing: false

Mac details:
Monerey 12.7.4.
I just click on wifi name and type password, all the standard options, I changed nothing.

Can you post the relevant system logs from "airportd" that contain wifi logs? (Or just do a sysdiagnose/log --collect)
